# How do I print 2 columns with looping from a file in bash

Tags: bash, loops, awk, while-loop, do-while

I have the following `output.txt` it consists only 2 columns to demonstrate:

```
Test1 Test1-IS-OK
Test2 Test2-IS-NOT
Test3 Test3-IS-OK
Test4 Test4-IS-OK
Test5 Test5-IS-NOT
```

Then my bash script has the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
output="output.txt"
a=$(awk '{ print $1 }' $output)
b=$(awk '{ print $2 }' $output)

while IFS=" " read -r $a $b
do
    echo "LOG: $a and $b"
done < "$output"
```

I got the following error:

```
./test.sh: line 13: read: `Test1-IS-OK': not a valid identifier
```

I need to have output like this

```
LOG: Test1 and Test1-IS-OK
LOG: Test2 and Test2-IS-NOT
LOG: Test3 and Test3-IS-OK
LOG: Test4 and Test4-IS-OK
LOG: Test5 and Test5-IS-NOT
```

But the code is not working. What is the best method to loop this 2 columns from a file? Is there a simpler method?

Comment: FWIW I upvoted as you had input, output, code and a problem statement but the text associated with the bash tag (hover your mouse over it) specifically says `For shell scripts with errors/syntax errors, please check them with the shellcheck program (or in the web shellcheck server at https://shellcheck.net) before posting here.` and if you'd done that then shellcheck would've answered your question instead of you having to post it here so that may be causing you to get some down votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are the problems with your code?

```
a=$(awk '{ print $1 }' $output)
```

With `echo "a=${a}"` you will see, that a is filled with the output for all lines. You were trying to make some find of function, to be called after `$a`.

```
while IFS=" " read -r $a $b
```

Now you are trying to call the "functions" a and b. The code will substitue the value of the variables before reading the inputfile. when a is filled with "Test1 Test2" the code will try to fill the fields `$Test1` and `$Test2`.

When you only want to change the output, without passing the variables to another statement, you can use `awk`, or

```
sed -E 's/([^ ]*) ([^ ]*).*/LOG: \1 and \2/' $output
# or
printf 'LOG: %s and %s\n' $(<$output)
```

In your case, you can make `read` reading two parameters:

```
while read -r a b 
do
    echo "LOG: $a and $b"
done < "$output"
```

Comment: Thanks, I accepted this answer because it explains what mistake I did in the code and the awk doesn't need to be inside loop for performance matter as mentioned by @anubhava

Comment: I deleted my incorrect `IFS=`. Please remember, that using `awk` inside a loop is wrong most of the times.

Answer (score 7):

Best is to avoid bash and do this completely in awk. Within awk it is as simple as:

```
awk '{print "LOG:", $1, "and", $2}' file
```

```
LOG: Test1 and Test1-IS-OK
LOG: Test2 and Test2-IS-NOT
LOG: Test3 and Test3-IS-OK
LOG: Test4 and Test4-IS-OK
LOG: Test5 and Test5-IS-NOT
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the tip on awk, but I prefer to use separate variable so I can pass that variable to other statement. upvoted your answer

Comment: `I prefer to use separate variable so I can pass that variable to other statement` _ may be if you clarify this then I can show how you can do that in awk itself.

Comment: Sorry, I mean I need to use the variable `$a` and `$b` and they need to be declared inside that loop because the are other statements inside that loop will be using this variable `$a` and `$b`. Thank you so much for your effort to help me on this. Actually the answer given by @Hilton Fernandes is what I meant.

Comment: That answer is actually hugely error prone and a bad practice. [Read this carefully](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: Indeed, @anubhava ! awk is powerful, and gawk is even more powerful.  It is a pity that it's not very used.

Comment: But sometimes you have no choice and need `awk` inside loop because you want to synchronize the result from awk for every changes. For example using `inotify: while inotifywait -q -e modify $some.txt  > /dev/null; do    your_awk_statement_on_some.txt done` You cannot put `your_awk_statement_on_some.txt` outside.

Answer (score 3):

Please consider transferring the `awk` parsing to the loop, where it belongs:

```
#!/bin/bash

output="output.txt"

while read -r line 
do
    a=$(echo "${line}" | awk '{print $1}')
    b=$(echo "${line}" | awk '{print $2}')
    echo "LOG: $a and $b"
done < "$output"
```

Edited according to a good suggestion by @EdMorton

Comment: `awk` is a program that will loop through a file, so it belongs outside the loop.

Comment: Indeed, but in the first version of the script, it would not generate the fields of each line as desired, but two lists of fields that require a lot more synchronization to parse in parallel.

Comment: I added a solution for a while-loop without calling `awk` inside the loop.

Comment: If you copy/paste that script into http://shellcheck.net it'll tell you about some, but not all, of the issues with it.

Answer (score 1):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -lane 'print "LOG: $F[0] and $F[1]";' output.txt > new.txt
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.
`-a` : Split `$_` into array `@F` on whitespace or on the regex specified in `-F` option.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)